# Getting error : 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am having a column which has date and time from a dataset. I am trying to create a new column with date only from this column.

`data['Event Date & Time Start']` contains

```
0    2014-05-21T14:00:00
1    2014-05-23T20:30:00
2    2014-05-24T08:00:00
3    2014-05-24T10:00:00
4    2014-05-26T13:00:00
5    2014-05-27T19:30:00
6    2014-05-29T09:30:00
7    2014-05-30T19:00:00
8    2014-05-31T08:00:00
9    2014-05-31T07:00:00
```

I am trying this

```
data['Date']=data['Event Date & Time Start'].apply(lambda i: i[:10])
```

I am getting error `'float' object is not subscriptable`.

Also while doing this :

```
for i in data["Event Date & Time Start"]:
    i[:10]
```

Same error is generated but instead of `i[:10]` if `print(i[:10])` is done, the date is getting printed. What is the reason?

Comment: Try printing each line and pay attention to where it fails. You'll easily find the offending line in file.

Comment: `print(i[:10])` should not in any way remove an error raised by `i[:10]` alone (`print` is a separate operation that is performed *after* `i[:10]` completes). You're doing something in code you haven't shown that triggers the problem. Please provide a [MCVE] that reproduces the problem; we can't guess at the problem from isolated snippets when the error likely isn't in the snippets.

Comment: If it's failing on the first element then you need to check that these are actually `str` values, otherwise you can't slice the `yyyy-mm-dd` portion the way you want to without converting with something like `datetime.datetime.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')`. If this method is successful up until a certain value, then you can use `enumerate(data["Event Date & Time Start"])` to quickly identify problematic indexes, i.e. values, and fix them.

Comment: okay got it. There are some values with NaN and that's why i was getting the error. Thanks